# Can I specify how long a response should be cached in AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, caching, afnetworking, asihttprequest, afnetworking-2

I'm a late convert from `ASIHTTPRequest` to `AFNetworking`. So far, AFN is much superior, but one feature I miss from ASI is the ability to specify how long a particular item should be cached, using the `ASICacheStoragePolicy` enum. It let you specify that an item should be cached only for this session, permanently or not at all.

Does something similar exist for `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of AFNetworking relies on two caching mechanism:

- NSCache for images
- NSURLCache the default caching class for NSURLConnection

Configuring the last one I'm sure that you can achieve what you want.
This is an [amazing blog article](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/) about this 2 mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

So, from [ASICacheDelegate.h](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASICacheDelegate.h) , we can read that:

```
// Cache storage policies control whether cached data persists between application launches (ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy) or not (ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy)
// Calling [ASIHTTPRequest clearSession] will remove any data stored using ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy
typedef enum _ASICacheStoragePolicy {
    ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy = 0,
    ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy = 1
} ASICacheStoragePolicy;
```

This [article](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/) from [Originate](http://www.originate.com) explains that [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) relies on [NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/).

So when you say you want to

> specify how long a response should be cached in [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

in regards of what [ASI](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) does, we are talking about application launches rather than seconds (or whatever units of time).

And because [NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) can be used as an in-memory cache (by default, which is reset between each app launch) or as an on-disk persistent cache, you should be able to attempt the desired behavior.

In short, doing nothing about [NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) will give you the behavior of `ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy`.

And the following snippet will give you the behavior of `ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy`:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                                        diskCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Lastly, if you want to have something like `[ASIHTTPRequest clearSession]` or if you want to manage your cache using units of time, [the same article](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/) has a section titled "**Subclass NSURLCache for Ultimate Control**".

AFAIK, there isn't a simple to do it using AFNetworking's APIs but that should be a good opportunity to contribute to an open source project :)

Comment: Good hhhhhhaggggg

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operation= [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] ;
operation.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
```

and the enum is:

```
enum
{
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};
typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;
```